# WPF Web Browser Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

we are using

> System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser

in my wpf application but that control is placed topmost(which is know for it), which leads to awkward UI.

in alternative to that we have used

> System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser

the ui issue has been resolved. But it din't full fill the necessary functionality.
We need to copy a web page content into our wpf control without losing any format and it should highlight all links. In particular, we have to open a ie process with the link clicked.

## Is there any wpf control for above requirement..

Comment: Your question is unclear. However, you said, *but wpf WebBrowser support only URI*... that's not at all true. You can use the [`WebBrowser.Navigate(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee169602(v=vs.110).aspx) or [WebBrowser.NavigateToStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostream(v=vs.110).aspx) methods, among others. If you want a proper answer, please ask a proper question, including details *of your actual problem*, along with a minimal, concise, working code example that exhibits your problem.

Comment: also clarify the "topmost and overlapping" part, the WPF `WebBrowser` is really just the same component under the hood.

Comment: sorry Sheridan & Nicholas, we hope now our query is crystal clear.. :-)